# Go GORM creates tables but not columns

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying to use a go script to setup my database with some tables.
The ORM I am using is GORM.

Here is the simplest setup I am using to achieve the task:

```
package main

import (
    "myapp/internal/database"
)

type Atable struct {
    acolumn bool
}

func main() {
    db := database.GetConnection()

    db.AutoMigrate(&Atable{})
    db.Create(Atable{
        acolumn: false,
    })
}
```

What this script does is creating the table but it is an empty table without any column.

What should I do in order to let GORM create the columns too?

If I add `gorm.Model` in the model declaration, only the 4 columns of the model are created (ID, CreatedAt, UpdatedAt, DeletedAt).

Comment: You need to [export](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) the fields. For more info, read: https://gorm.io/docs/models.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try capitalizing the first letter. like

```
type Atable struct {
    Acolumn bool
}
```